# Apache on Centos 7 abruptly dies

Tags: linux, apache, centos7

Since a few days, Apache on my Centos 7 server dies sometime after I restart it. I even tried to reboot the machine to no avail.
Immediately afte resting it, it does respond, but afte a while it stop doing it an if I execute:

```
sudo systemctl status httpd.service
```

I get:

> httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server    Loaded: loaded
>   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)    Active: inactive
>   (dead)

I fixed the issue by reinstalling Apache.

Comment: As a start, you could check the Apache log files and see if they provide anything useful. It's been a while since I used CentOS, but I think the log file is in `/var/log/httpd`

(see here: http://superuser.com/questions/511781/access-apache-log-files-in-centos )

Comment: Yes, it is called error_log and reports nothing really useful, but for a long list of errors of the kind:
sh: /usr/local/bin/python3.3: No such file or directory
I do not know from which they are created.

Comment: I found this: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/47110   The problem for them was that the command to rotate logs would kill the Apache daemon once every day when it was supposed to restart it. Their workaround was to create an override.conf that restarted apache if it was not running.

Comment: The issue is that the problem arose by itself without me changing any configuration after two years of activity. It is unlikely such a behavior arose by itself. Anyway what i the procedure to restart apache should it be terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The override they report using at https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/47110 goes in file `/etc/logwatch/conf/override.conf`

```
[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
ExecReload=/usr/bin/httpd -k graceful
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND
```

Comment: Should that snippet of code been inserted in the httpd.conf file? At any rate the night it did not die, for no known reason.

Comment: Farbrizio: I edited the answer to include the full path for you.

Comment: The server went down again tonight. Please inform what I may do about it as the provider declared their incompetence regarding apache. For the time being I switched the DNS to access the sites on another server, but I would like to have the situation restored as soon as possibile.

Comment: I miss a logwatch directory, should I create it? In that case, how do I say to the system to look for it and test it?

Comment: The server went down again, notwistanding I set the suggested file in the location indicated. What should I do next? As it is the server has become all but useless.